# How to center text on circle?

Tags: php, image, text, gd, geometry

in php, is there an easy way to draw text with [**imagettftext**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) and [**imagefilledarc**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledarc.php) at center, considering font and font size?

**Example**:
I'm using Verdana Bold, size 16 and i want to center "1234567890" text in my circle.

```
$font = './verdanab.ttf';
$fsize = 16;
$text = "1234567890";
imagefilledarc ($im, $cx, $cy, $w, $h, 0, 360, $color, 0);
imagettftext   ($im, $fs, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);
```

how can i do it automatically resized, considering font changing ?

Could also use [**imagefontwidth**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefontwidth.php) ?
Is there a function that count font pixels width?

Sample shot:
[image]

Comment: If you know the size of the text, you can calculate it's position relative to the circle center by substracting the half of the text's width and the half of text's height from `$cx` and `$cy`. To get the text's size see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved using

```
$txtSize = imagettfbbox($fs, 0, $font, $text); // idx [2] is text width in pixel

$buffer = 20;
$w = $h = $txtSize[2] + $buffer;
$x = $cx - ($txtSize[2]/2);

imagefilledarc ($im, $cx, $cy, $w, $h, 0, 360, $color, 0);
imageAlphaBlending($im, true);
imagettftext   ($im, $fs, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);
```

thanks.